# Speeding Up Nested For Loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to speed up some code, which is really slow.  First, I have a data structure called raw, which I will paste a subset of below (it's quite large -- 3045162 observations).

I'm trying to count up (1,2,3,4,5,6) from the first point at which the RIGHT_IN_SACCADE variable changes from 0 to 1, for each combination of t_trialNum and t_subjNum.  I have accomplished this task using nested for loops:

```
subjlist <- unique(raw$t_subjNum)
triallist <- unique(raw$t_trialNum)
raw$saccindex <- 0
raw$aftersaccade <- 0
for(s in subjlist){
   for(t in triallist){
      index <- which(raw$t_subjNum == s & raw$t_trialNum == t)
      raw$aftersaccade[index] <- cumsum(raw$RIGHT_IN_SACCADE[index])
      raw$aftersaccade[index] <- ifelse(raw$aftersaccade[index] > 1, 1, 0)
      raw$saccindex[index]<- cumsum(raw$aftersaccade[index])
   }
   print(s)
}
```

As a C programmer, it's generally hard for me to imagine how to vectorize.  Any advice?

Comment: I think you forgot to add the example of your data...?

Comment: The data is just too large to paste or even upload to my university website.  Here's a link to a subset of the raw data on my professional website: https://sites.google.com/site/nickgaspelin/data/stackoverflow.Rdata?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: There are usually two standard solutions.  "Think really hard" and find a faster (vectorized) algorithm.  Or just use C/C++ via Rcpp.

Comment: `dput(droplevels(head(your_data, 10)))` works great for sharing the first 10 rows of data. Of just simulate an **minimal working** example - it sounds like there are only 3 columns that matter for this particular problem. If it's any encouragement, this sounds like a very easy data table or dplyr problem.

Comment: The dput trick is handy.  But you'd need about 2000 rows of data to see one trial.  It's a very large data set.

Comment: In which case simulating a small illustrative example is the preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

With base R I would generally reach for `ave` when faced with a within-groups calculation on one vector:

```
raw$saccindex <- with( raw, 
      ave(RIGHT_IN_SACCADE,  interaction( t_subjNum, t_trialNum), # 2nd arg is grp-vec
                           FUN= function(x) cumsum( cumsum(x) > 1 ) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading through your code, I think this is what you want, using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
raw %>% group_by(t_subjNum, t_trialNum) %>%
        mutate(aftersaccade = +(cumsum(RIGHT_IN_SACCADE) > 1),
               saccindex = cumsum(aftersaccade))
```

For every combination of subject and trial, we are getting an `aftersaccade` column, which is a 1 or 0, depending on if the cumsum of `RIGHT_IN_SACCADE` is > 1.

Then we get a saccindex, which is the `cumsum` of `aftersaccade`

Comment: `+()` with a single argument seems like a pretty obscure way to convert a boolean to integer. Why not use `as.integer()` to be clear or just leave it as boolean?